# UnimplementedError: Graph execution error:

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, conv-neural-network, seaborn, lstm

So I have been facing this error while implementing this CNN Code for my project. Can somebody please help me out?

I have tried using older versions of tensorflow and tried cleaning my dataset once again to fix this error but it doesn't seem to solve the issue.

After trying several times by changing the parameters or cleaning the dataset i have been facing this error:

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv1D
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTM
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Embedding
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Activation
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dropout
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.layers import AveragePooling1D, AveragePooling2D, AveragePooling3D, MaxPooling1D
```

```
cnn_model = Sequential()

cnn_model.add(Conv1D(100, 1, activation="relu", input_shape=(X_train_reshape.shape[0], 1)))

cnn_model.add(Dense(50, activation="relu"))

cnn_model.add(Conv1D(50, 1, activation="relu"))
cnn_model.add(Conv1D(25, 1, activation="relu"))
cnn_model.add(Conv1D(12, 1, activation="relu"))
cnn_model.add(Conv1D(6, 1, activation="relu"))

cnn_model.add(Dense(3, activation="relu"))
cnn_model.add(Dense(1, activation="relu"))

cnn_model.add(Conv1D(1, 1, activation="softmax"))

print(cnn_model.summary())
# Producing Neural Network
cnn_model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',  # Loss function
            optimizer="adam",  # Gradient Descent
            metrics=['accuracy'])  # Accuracy score
```

```
cnn_model.fit(X_test_reshape,y_test_reshape, epochs=80, batch_size=10, verbose=0)
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnimplementedError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-65d435d7d5b3> in <module>
----> 1 cnn_model.fit(X_train_reshape,y_train_reshape, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=verbose)

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     53     ctx.ensure_initialized()
     54     tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
---> 55                                         inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
     56   except core._NotOkStatusException as e:
     57     if name is not None:

UnimplementedError: Graph execution error:

Detected at node 'sequential/Cast' defined at (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
      "__main__", mod_spec)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
      exec(code, run_globals)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py", line 16, in <module>
      app.launch_new_instance()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 846, in launch_instance
      app.start()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelapp.py", line 612, in start
      self.io_loop.start()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tornado/platform/asyncio.py", line 132, in start
      self.asyncio_loop.run_forever()
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/asyncio/base_events.py", line 541, in run_forever
      self._run_once()
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1786, in _run_once
      handle._run()
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/asyncio/events.py", line 88, in _run
      self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 758, in _run_callback
      ret = callback()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 300, in null_wrapper
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1233, in inner
      self.run()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1147, in run
      yielded = self.gen.send(value)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 365, in process_one
      yield gen.maybe_future(dispatch(*args))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 326, in wrapper
      yielded = next(result)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 268, in dispatch_shell
      yield gen.maybe_future(handler(stream, idents, msg))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 326, in wrapper
      yielded = next(result)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 545, in execute_request
      user_expressions, allow_stdin,
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 326, in wrapper
      yielded = next(result)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/ipkernel.py", line 306, in do_execute
      res = shell.run_cell(code, store_history=store_history, silent=silent)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/zmqshell.py", line 536, in run_cell
      return super(ZMQInteractiveShell, self).run_cell(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2855, in run_cell
      raw_cell, store_history, silent, shell_futures)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2881, in _run_cell
      return runner(coro)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/async_helpers.py", line 68, in _pseudo_sync_runner
      coro.send(None)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3058, in run_cell_async
      interactivity=interactivity, compiler=compiler, result=result)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3249, in run_ast_nodes
      if (await self.run_code(code, result,  async_=asy)):
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3326, in run_code
      exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
    File "<ipython-input-26-65d435d7d5b3>", line 1, in <module>
      cnn_model.fit(X_train_reshape,y_train_reshape, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=verbose)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 64, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1409, in fit
      tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1051, in train_function
      return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1040, in step_function
      outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1030, in run_step
      outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 889, in train_step
      y_pred = self(x, training=True)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 64, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 490, in __call__
      return super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 64, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 1014, in __call__
      outputs = call_fn(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 92, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/sequential.py", line 374, in call
      return super(Sequential, self).call(inputs, training=training, mask=mask)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/functional.py", line 459, in call
      inputs, training=training, mask=mask)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/functional.py", line 578, in _run_internal_graph
      y = self._conform_to_reference_input(y, ref_input=x)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/functional.py", line 678, in _conform_to_reference_input
      tensor = tf.cast(tensor, dtype=ref_input.dtype)
Node: 'sequential/Cast'
Cast string to float is not supported
     [[{{node sequential/Cast}}]] [Op:__inference_train_function_1125]
```

Comment: @JirayuKaewprateep

Comment: @user:7848579  Can you plz check

Comment: Hi @Pulkit, please share minimal reproducible code to replicate the issue and assist you better. Thank you!

Comment: Sure @Tfer3, have a look

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using colab? Just swith gpu to tpu. It might works.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).